# ¿Por qué no recibo el id en el request?

Tags: laravel-5, tdd

Estoy trabajando con Laravel, tengo la siguiente prueba:

```
    /** @test */
public function a_job_can_be_stored_in_database()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $company = factory('App\Company')->create();

    $job = factory('App\Job')->make([
        'description' => 'we are looking for cheff helper'
    ]);

    $this->post(route('jobs.store'), $job->toArray());
    $this->assertDatabaseHas('jobs', [
        'description' => 'we are looking for cheff helper'
    ]);
}
```

Ese ruta me lleva al controlador `Job` y hago el llamado al método `store`.

```
public function store(Company $company)
{

    $company->addJob([
        'city_id' => request('city_id'),
        'title' => request('title'),
        'description' => request('description'),
        'requirements' => request('requirements'),
        'salary' => request('salary'),
        'address' => request('address')
    ]);

    return redirect(route('jobs.index'));
}
```

y dentro del método `store` hago el llamado a otro método que está en el modelo `Company` que es el siguiente:

```
public function addJob($data)
{
    return $this->jobs()->create($data);
}
```

y este es el error que me arroja la prueba:

```
Tests\Feature\JobFeatureTest::a_job_can_be_stored_in_database
```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: **Integrity constraint violation**: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: **jobs.company_id** (SQL: insert into "jobs" ("city_id", "title", "description", "requirements", "salary", "address", **"company_id"**, "updated_at", "created_at") values (3, Proofreaders and Copy Marker, we are looking for cheff helper, Exercitationem amet quas., 1000, 4515 Langworth Oval
North Arianeburgh, AL 36445, , 2018-12-13 04:58:19, 2018-12-13 04:58:19))

Osea, me dice que no estoy pasando un valor al campo company_id, he intentado agregando en el request el campo pero me da el mismo error osea no me toma el valor de company_id para almacenarlo.. agradezco cualquier consejo, saludos.

Comment: En `store()` en el  `$company->addJob`  no se incluye `company_id`  ¿donde se supone que lo agregas?

Comment: saludos, ese es el punto, tambien ya he probado haciendo el request del company_id y tampoco me toma el valor, osea incluyo **'company_id' => request('company_id')** y me da el mismo error

Comment: Y podrías mostrar el html desde donde envía el `company_id` junto con `city_id` y el resto de campos del request ?

Comment: estoy enviando la data desde un @test aun no he creado mi formulario

Answer (score 0):

despues de algunas horas de analizar mi codigo e investigar me di cuenta que mi error era que no estaba usando el model binding correctamente, una vez que pase el parametro atravez de la ruta funciono mi codigo, mi prueba quedo de la siguiente manera, aca pongo otro test pero es basicamente la misma situacion.

```
public function temporalTest()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $song = factory('App\Song')->make(['name' => 'charlie']);

    $this->post(route('songs.store', $song->artist_id), $song->toArray());

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('songs',[
        'name' => 'charlie'
    ]);
}
```